# Statistical reason for wanting to keep the variance of a feature column with missing values constant before and after data handling

Tags: variance

I am given a dataset with multiple numerical features where each feature column contains some data with missing values. I am asked to insert appropriate values for the missing data in each feature column in order to keep the variance in each column constant before and after the data insertion. Each variance is different across columns.

My question is whether there is a specific reason or statistical concept where we would like to preserve the variance of each feature column constant before and after the insertion of data in the missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that data is missing completely at random (MCAR), missingness carries no information. You should expect to see no meaningful difference at all between the distribution of the actual values whether the observation is present or not. If your summary statistics (mean, variance, etc.) change after the imputation of missing data, it must be the case that the distribution is different between your missing and non-missing population. This violates the assumption that the data was MCAR in the first place - if only large values show up as missing, for example, that's a very important trend to know about. If you don't keep your summary statistics constant, you are implicitly forcing the dataset to be not MCAR. Note that MCAR-ness may or may not be an appropriate starting point for your analysis, so it may not always make sense to keep your summary statistics constant.

Comment: I think you mean missing completely at random. Missing at random is a different thing.

Comment: @astel Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight and your help @NuclearHoagie. Unfortunately I cannot upvote the answer since I dont have enough reputation but it helped me a lot to continue my investigation on the matter. I will make sure to upvote it when I reach the reputation barrier.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I would like one more clarification if possible.Since a distribution can be adequately described by its shape,its central tendency and how it is dispersed, it seems reasonable to me to want a set of summary statistics like (mean,variance) to be constant together between the observed and missing population since that would provide strong evidence that they might be following the same distribution. However I cannot think of a case where only the variance might be needed to be constant. Perhaps you have any insight on that too? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Pristakos Hm, I can't think of a reason why you'd want to keep variance but not necessarily mean constant after imputing data. Depending on how you choose to impute data, you might fill in missing values with variance-appropriate values, which will naturally represent variation around some mean. So it's possible that keeping the variance constant might also keep the mean constant as a side-effect, so that you don't need to explicitly worry about it. I can't think of a situation where you'd want to keep the variance but not the mean after imputation, though.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie highly appreciate your time and help! Thank you very much!